# Android - saving a position of a page when pausing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I got a `ViewPager` which saves the current page position (as the order in it's adapter). When the app goes to the backgroung, the ViewPager seem to lose the position it was last in and when switching to the app again, it starts at fragment with the position 0.

How can I save the current position and set the correct fragment? Hopefully it's something that needs to be done in a single place only and not in every fragment.

Comment: mabe showing some code would give us some ideas to see whats going on

Comment: Try overrding `onPause()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so it eventually was just something standard. I just overrided `OnPause` and `OnResume`. I saved the state with a `SharedPreferences` in the `OnPause` method and restored it in the `OnResume` method.

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    final SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences("name",
            android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    ed.putInt(INDEX_KEY_STRING, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    ed.commit();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    final SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("name",
            android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(sp.getInt(INDEX_KEY_STRING, 0));
}
```

Comment: Simple enough implementation made a difference on the UX of the App. Thanks